# Почему метод не возвращает true, false?

Tags: java

Есть задача, ее условие - Написать метод, в который передается не пустой одномерный целочисленный массив, метод должен вернуть true если в массиве есть место, в котором сумма левой и правой части массива равны.
Я написал сам метод, в нем я сначала полностью считаю массив, а потом справа вычитаю элементы, а слева их прибавляю, и жду когда условие выполнится. Сам метод отрабатывает, но true или false не отдает, почему? (т.е. я понимаю, что в консоли у меня должно появиться необходимое значение)

```
public class Lesson {
    public static boolean hw6(int[] array){

        System.out.println("hw6");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));

        int left = 0, right = 0;

        for (int i:array) {
            right += i;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (left == right) {
                return true;
            }
            left += array[i];
            right -= array[i];
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Добавлю, что главный метод выглядит так -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3};
    Lesson.hw6(array);
}
```

Comment: А как вы проверяете что он возвращает? В коде вижу только вызов метода, но нигде не используется значение, которое было возвращено. Даже более, это значение никуда не принимается. Исключительно вызов.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Метод возвращает значение, но Вы с ним ничего не делаете.

В методе `hw6` вы выводите в консоль информацию:

```
System.out.println("hw6");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

С результатом выполнения метода нужно сделать так же само:

```
System.out.println(Lesson.hw6(array));
```

Comment: я был уверен, что без `println` в консоли появится вывод true, действительно, с чего бы это, как я понял если методы с возвратом (не void) при необходимости вывода информации, надо использовать `System.out.println`